# HTML5 Video in Amazon FireTV Apps

Tags: android, html, cordova, cordova-plugins, amazon-fire-tv

Pretty basic question.

I am using PhoneGap/Cordova (http://www.phonegap.com) to build an app for Amazon FireTV OS, which is built on Android. I am using HTML, Javascript, CSS and everything is working fine. However, when I try to use the < video > tag to pull in an .MP4 video, all I am getting is a gray background and film strip logo (picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCHHB.jpg). What does this mean? The documentation says  is supported and I am 100% positive of the path and any other silly pitfalls. Do I need a cordova plugin of some sort? Perhaps the manifest file needs to be tweaked? Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't provide the code, I will try to form how I have done it before:

1. Make sure your code does not have `video.load();` for android
2. You must call `video.play();`

   - example:

   `video.addEventListener('click',function(){
       video.play();
    },false);`
3. If you trigger play please call `video.pause();` before you call `video.play();`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have attached my code. Where would I place the code you mentioned? As you can see, I simply have one line which is calling the <video> tag: http://www.sendspace.com/file/kb29g9

Comment: Since your video can't play, so i wrote this example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8m6Ta/), also you can check this out: [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp), hope this can help.